# How to truncate floats precision to enable two similar float are treated the same

Tags: javascript

Let say I have two floats
`0.1788877` and `0.17777231` I only want to convert them in to 0.17 and truncate all the remaining precisions.

For example, FN(0.1788877) === FN(0.17777231) should return TRUE.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

`Number#toFixed(x)` returns a string representing the number with the maximum of `x` digits after the decimal point.

Contverting that string to a number by `+` will produce the expected result:

```
const FN=num=>+num.toFixed(2)
```